# How to simplify an expression with simple symbolic integrations with the same boundaries?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I am new to Mathematica and I am trying to simplify an expression with symbolic integrals as below

> ```
> $Assumptions = ph >pl > 0
> >     AppendTo[$Assumptions , dp>0]
> AppendTo[$Assumptions , b0>bm>0]
> >     AppendTo[$Assumptions , M>0]
> AppendTo[$Assumptions , R>0]
> >     AppendTo[$Assumptions , ph*R-1-M>0]
> AppendTo[$Assumptions , ph*(bm/dp-R)+1+M>0]
> >     AppendTo[$Assumptions , ph*(b0/dp-R)+1>0]
> AppendTo[$Assumptions , U>0]
> >     AppendTo[$Assumptions , c>0]
> AppendTo[$Assumptions , t>0]
> >     AppendTo[$Assumptions , 1>K4>K3>K2>K1>0]
>
> FullSimplify[((U-((U+c-Integrate[f[K]*(ph*R-1-M),{K,K1,K3}]-2Integrate[f[K]*(K-ph*bm/dp),{K,K1,K2}])/2))+Integrate[f[K]*(ph*bm/dp-K),{K,K1,K2}])/t, $Assumptions]
> ```

and I get the following output:

[image]

I don't understand why the first and second integrals do not cancel each other. In general, I don't manage to get simple symbolic integrals with the same boundaries simplified even when I use `Simplify[]` or `FullSimplify[]`.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Assumptions = 
  ph > pl > 0 && dp > 0 && b0 > bm > 0 && M > 0 && R > 0 && 
   ph*R - 1 - M > 0 && ph*(bm/dp - R) + 1 + M > 0 && 
   h*(b0/dp - R) + 1 > 0 && U > 0 && c > 0 && t > 0 && 
   1 > K4 > K3 > K2 > K1 > 0;
```

When you use [`$Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html), the assumptions are made available to any function that takes the option [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) without having to explicitly add the `Assumptions` option.

```
Expand[((U - ((U + c - Integrate[f[K]*(ph*R - 1 - M), {K, K1, K3}] - 
            2 Integrate[f[K]*(K - ph*bm/dp), {K, K1, K2}])/2)) + 
      Integrate[f[K]*(ph*bm/dp - K), {K, K1, K2}])/t] /. 
          {a1_.*Integrate[expr1_, iter_] + 
             a2_.*Integrate[expr2_, iter_] + r___ :> 
            Integrate[a1*expr1 + a2*expr2, iter] + r} // 
  Simplify
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.
Here is your expression:

```
expr = ((U - ((U + c - Integrate[f[K]*(ph*R - 1 - M), {K, K1, K3}] - 
           2 Integrate[f[K]*(K - ph*bm/dp), {K, K1, K2}])/2)) + 
     Integrate[f[K]*(ph*bm/dp - K), {K, K1, K2}])/t // Expand
```

Let us divide it into two expressions:

```
exprA = Together[Take[expr, {3, 4}]]
exprB = expr - Take[expr, {3, 4}]
```

The former contains the sum of integrals that you want to transform. The latter is  the rest.

Let us introduce a rule:

```
rule = Integrate[g1__, {K, a_, b_}] + Integrate[g2__, {K, a_, b_}] :> 
   Integrate[Simplify[g1 + g2], {K, a, b}];
```

and apply it to exprA:

```
exprA = Together[Take[expr, {3, 4}]]
```

[image]
Now, the desired result is

```
(exprA /. rule) + exprB
```

[image]

Have fun!